# Performance: Iterate linq VS iterate datatable

Tags: c#, performance, winforms

A general culture question:

In a relatively small set of records (5000 records for example) it would be more optimal to iterate over Linq objects or over a Datatable.

Example with linq:

```
var _rows_ref_carga = from _row in list_cargas
                 where ref_carga == "XXXXX"
                 select _row;
                 

foreach (var _r in _rows_ref_carga)   {
   OTHER OPERATION
}
```

Example with DataTable:

```
 foreach (DataRow _r in _datatable.Rows)   {
       OTHER OPERATION
    }
```

My question is: iterate over "_rows_ref_carga" is more efficient that iterate over "_datatable.Rows" ???

Thanks.

Comment: Have you run any perf tests yet?

Comment: Not yet, I am finishing a Linq course and I have doubts about the performance of iterating over a set of registers on which I will later have to perform other operations.

I was asking for the opinion of programmers with experience with Linq.

(in any case I will do the performance test by myself)

Thank you

Comment: More optimal than what? LINQ *can be used* on a DataTable, so it isn't clear what backend you're talking about for the LINQ part here. DataTable is very rarely the answer in any performance question. If you're talking about holding the data in memory for a reasonable time (not fetching it every operation), then yes that can be helpful, but  maybe via a `List<T>`?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I am currently working on a project with DataTables and the performance of the operations performed is good (all operations with data are performed with DataTables).

The List <t> is an option that we are introducing but most of the code is legacy and if it can be improved with Linq I will push for its use in any new associated development. Thank you

Comment: @raBinn you're misunderstanding me; LINQ is an approach, not a specific thing. There are a dozen interpretations of "with LINQ". What **exactly** are you trying to compare here? And more to the point: have you simply measured them?

Comment: I am going to edit the question and I am going to put a couple of code examples because I have not specified my question well.  And more to the point: have you simply measured them? > Not yet, I am finishing a Linq course and I have doubts about the performance of iterating over a set of registers on which I will later have to perform other operations.

Answer (score 2):

With the edit, it looks like you're comparing LINQ-to-Objects over a DataTable, vs foreach over a DataTable (with a Where vs an if). This would be a great thing to investigate with a benchmarking tool such as benchmarkdotnet with your realistic data. Other things to consider:

- how many matches do you expect? If it is 1, would a dictionary be a better idea? Or a ToLookup? (Assuming the data doesn't change constantly)
- would a List-T have fewer overheads?

However! Yes, LINQ-To-Objects adds a layer of abstraction and indirection, which means: overheads. Normally this overhead isn't important, and the clarity of code is worth it. If the code in question is performance critical, then the `foreach` with `if` would usually be measurably quicker, but only by a little. The more relevant factors are usually:

1. Can you improve the underlying store? (Hence my mention of list, dictionary, lookup), and
2. Can you improve the OTHER OPERATION, which is usually the main time taken; if the iteration is only 0.1% of the cost *anyway*, improving it isn't a good use of your time

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it is quite clarifying.

In any case, I'm going to do a test with real data to see what results I get.

Thanks a lot for your time.